# Why aren't antennas placed at the ceiling of a microwave oven

Tags: electromagnetic, microwave

From what I have understand, microwave ovens work by emitting microwave electromagnetic waves from some antenna.   Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In my microwave oven I have seen some empty holes at the left side of and I assumed that from there the waves are emitted. That would explain why whenever I heat food inside a bowl and not a plate, the bowl ends up becoming really heated while the inside not so much due to attenuation.

Why aren't the wave emitters placed in the ceiling of the oven?

Comment: It doesn't matter, as the waves bounces from the walls - cavity.

Comment: Most microwave ovens use a waveguide which works well at 2.4GHz.

Comment: The holes are for air flow.  The microwave energy comes in from the top or the side of the cavity through a microwave-transparent (plastic) cover, from the waveguide.

Comment: The bowl becomes hot 1) if it is not microwave safe, or 2) because the outer parts of whatever is in the bowl heats up faster than the interior, which in turn heats up the bowl.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Sometimes there is even a spinning fan in the radiation pattern to farther "randomize" the path of the reflected energy.  Add a turn-y table, and it's popcorn for everyone!

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Yes, I know. I have seen those while on business trip in USA. Here in EU you get just a rotating plate inside, don't know why. I really liked the US version, but I don't understand why they sell only this boring rotating dish here in EU.

Comment: A metal plate with holes in it looks like a metal plate to microwaves.  So -- what @SteveSh said about where they actually come from.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly an antenna.  Instead, it's a capacitive stub; a waveguide-probe (cavity-probe) driving a resonant "circuit."

If you wanted the emitter in the ceiling, just turn the entire microwave oven on its side, so that the magnetron tube is above the oven cavity, rather than on the side.  (See the problem?  People want to buy wide, low-slung ovens, rather than ovens which resemble a miniature refrigerator!)

Antennas: driven cavity-resonance includes some weird physics beyond that of the conventional dipole antennas emitting EM waves into free space (the effects are similar to laser phenomena and atoms radiating into optical cavities.)   Unexpectedly, waveguide-probes can be physically short, yet still emit high wattage while showing the impedance of a much longer dipole antenna.  The short probe is driving into the synchronized fields of a waveguide, as well as driving against the strong fields of an existing standing-wave.  The tip of the magnetron tube can behave more like one plate of a capacitor, than like a quarter-wave dipole antenna.